# How can i use field of view in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst

The field of view analysis in GIS is a polygon file that shows the portions of an area that are visible versus no visible across a terrain starting from a given point. see this [Link](http://www.gislounge.com/line-of-sight-in-gis/)

How can I use Field of view analysis in ArcGIS? is there any tools to use field of view analysis in ArcGIS or any scripts ?

Comment: Have you looked into Viewshed analysis?

Comment: @Jay Guarneri. viewshed only use point and polyline observer feature. do you know any tools to use polygon file for view analysis ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to convert the polygon to polylines, then run the viewshed analysis.  You can then reclassify the areas within the polygons to Visible using a Con() statement, just to cover your bases.

Comment: +1 Great answer.  Sorry, I overlapped your answer--didn't see it until too late.

Comment: No problem!! :)  Glad you like my solution.

Comment: The nodes and vertices of lines will be used as observation points. is it true for polygons ?

Comment: I imagine it would work the same.

Answer (score 3):

The [Viewshed (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000v3000000) or (3d Analyst) tool can be used to perform that analysis.  Arc does a good job at viewshed analysis.  For an added level of detail, drape the viewshade raster over a hillshade in ArcScene, as shown in this screenshot.

Edit:

To accomplish this analysis using polygons, simply convert them to polylines using [Polygon to Line (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003t000000).

[image]

Or over aerial imagery with illumination in ArcScene:

[image]