# how to obtain a shapefile of 2D FOV from EXIF?

Tags: export

I allow myself to contact you about a topic for which I saw you writte an answer on this discussion :

[How can i use field of view in ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57197/how-can-i-use-field-of-view-in-arcgis)

So maybe you will be able to help me.

I have a serie of landscape photos that I would like to locate on a map with a simple 2D field o view.

I found the perfect functionality on geosetter :

[image: the softaward automaticaly uses the EXIF data of the photo to create a shape of the field of view]

But what I would like to do is to export this shape in any format that gis (such as arcgis) could read... Geosetter is able to export in KMZ for google earth (so it would be possible from KMZ to get a shape), but, unfortunaltely, it only export the location point of the photo and not the shape of the FOV... Would you have any idea to 1) export the geosetter shape or 2) create such a shape directly on arc GIS... ?

I dont know if I am very clear, because my english is not realy fluent... but I hope you will be able to understand something and maybe help me answer this question ...